AppsFlyer invitation with expo development build
Is there a proper way to integrate Unified Deep Linking (deferred deep linking) into an Expo React Native app, and successfully test it with expo development build?
We managed to handle the part with generating an invitation link (generateInviteLink) for each user.
However, how can I test if this invitation link is actually working using an Expo development build?
The simplified scenario is:
I don't have the app installed.
I click on the generated link.
The Expo development build gets installed from that link.
I test the rest of the flow (and referral/invitation data) through it.
Thanks!
I am not sure how to configure both expo and appsflyer, so these generated links can open expo development build in order for me to test/develop the rest of the flow
